# importance sampling and exponential moving average

Tags: moving-average, importance-sampling

Lets say i have got a random variable $X$ with samples $x_t\sim X$ and density $p_X(x)$ and want to compute its mean via a moving average

$ \mu_{t+1}=(1-c)\mu_t + c x_t$

Assume, I can not observe $X$ directly, but instead a random variable $Y$ with density $p_Y(y)$ and samples $y_t\sim Y$. I would like to use importance sampling to compute the mean.

The naive approach is with $w_t=\frac{p_X(y_t)}{p_Y(y_t)}$

$ \mu_{t+1}=\left(1- cw_t\right)\mu_t + c w_t y_t$

This works, as long as the importance weights are small. However, if $w_t> \frac 1 c$ the above formula is obviously not correct any more. Is there a way to correct for this? It should be clear that as $w_t \rightarrow \infty$, $\mu_{t+1}\rightarrow y_t$

//edit the approach I tried to is using a sample-size estimate, but i am not sure this is correct.

The initial estimate has an estimated $1/c$ samples stored. Assuming we can interpret $w_t$ as sample-size correction, we can just try to average according to how many samples we got:

$ \mu_{t+1}=\left(1- \frac{w_t}{w_t + \frac 1 c -1}\right)\mu_t + \frac{w_t}{w_t+\frac 1 c-1} y_t$

for $w_t=1$ this gives the original update $\frac 1 c-1$ is the totally stored number of samples in the path after "forgetting the oldest"

but i have no idea how to show that this is correct, this is just an educated guess

Answer (score 0):

I am answering myself. Still not with a proof, but with a better solution.

Assume first a slightly different setup, where instead of a single number $y_t$, we get a sample average $\bar{y}_t$ from $n_t$ samples. Clearly, if $n_t$ is large, we would like to trust it a lot and unlearn much of the previous samples. if afterwards, $n_{t+1}$ is small, we would not want to unlearn the good sample quickly.

The correct way to handle this is to have two variables: one which is an exponentially decaying sum of the number of samples

$N_{t+1}= (1-c) N_t + n_t$
Note that when $n_t=1$ for all $t$, this will converge to $N=1/c$.

The update of the mean $\mu_{t+1}$ is just the correctly weighted average of two means with different number of samples:
$\mu_{t+1}=(1-\frac {n_t}{N_{t+1}}) \mu_t + \frac {n_t}{N_{t+1}} \bar{y}_t$

The same now holds trivially when replacing $n_t$ with $w_t$.

I have no doubt about the $\mu_{t+1}$ update and it also makes sense with importance sampling. I am not sure about the $N_t$, but I think it is probably hard to come up with a perfect justification for any type of exponential moving average.